# How to reset QApplication::styleSheet for certain buttons in application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

In my main() function I'm setting styleSheet on all buttons of my application.

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                            "     border: 1px solid #8f8f91;"
                            "     border-radius: 4px;"
                            "     background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #f6f7fa, stop: 1 #dadbde);"
                            "     padding: 3px;"
                            " }");
```

But now I need to reset the style of some buttons. I've tried `button->setStyleSheet("")`, but it is not working. So, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

What you can do is the opposite, i.e. **setting** the stylesheet for certain buttons like this:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton[specialButton=\"true\"] {"
                    "     border: 1px solid #8f8f91;"
                    "     border-radius: 4px;"
                    "     background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #f6f7fa, stop: 1 #dadbde);"
                    "     padding: 3px;"
                    "}");
```

and then:

```
button->setProperty("specialButton", true);
```

This way only the buttons with *specialButton* set to `true` will have the custom look, the others will look normal.